# Add some fields of obj in another obj

Tags: javascript, object, merge

In my example the OBJ (scope.fields) is always the default and the OBJ (scope.grupos) would add only within the OBJ (scope.fields) the model field.

But with this function below could not, I tried the underscore.js and lodash.js unsuccessfully as well. He keeps the OBJ keys (scope.grupos).

Only the model field can be inserted.

```
  function merge(obj1, obj2) {
    var result = {};
    for (i in obj1) {
      result[i] = obj1[i];
      if ((i in obj2) && (typeof obj1[i] === "object") && (i !== null)) {
        result[i] = merge(obj1[i], obj2[i]);
      }
    }
    for (i in obj2) {
      if (i in result) { //conflict
        continue;
      }
      result[i] = obj2[i];
    }
    return result;
  }
```

JSON data:

```
  //GRUPOS CRIADOS SEGUIR ESTE JSON
  $scope.fields = [{
    "fields": [{
      "type": "input",
      "title": "Nome do projeto",
      "key": "projeto-name",
      "obs": "Adicione aqui o nome do projeto."
    }],
    "id": "1",
    "posted": "2015-08-05T06:42:11.598Z",
    "title": "Projetos",
    "show": "posts"
  }, {
    "fields": [{
      "type": "checkbox"
    }, {
      "type": "checkbox"
    }],
    "id": "2",
    "posted": "2015-08-06T22:37:16.046 Z",
    "title": "Categorias dos Projetos",
    "show": "posts"
  }];




  // GRUPO DO POST
  $scope.grupo = [{
    "id": "1",
    "posted": "2015-08-05T06:42:11.598Z",
    "title": "Projetos",
    "show": "posts",
    "fields": [{
      "type": "input",
      "title": "Nome do projeto",
      "key": "projeto-name",
      "obs": "Adicione aqui o nome do projeto.",
      "model": "Projeto teste"
    }],
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "posted": "2015-08-05T07:03:23.054 Z ",
    " title ": "Super teste ",
    "show ": " posts",
    "fields": [{
      "type": "input",
      "title": "Campo de texto simples",
      "key": "simples",
      "obs": "fdsdsdsdsdsd",
      "required": true,
      "model": "Agora é um super teste"
    }, {
      "type": "textarea",
      "title": "Campo de texto longo",
      "key": "longo",
      "obs": "dsfsdfsdfsdfsdf",
      "required": true,
      "model": "Superrrrrr testeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
    }],
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "posted": "2015-08-06T22:37:16.046Z",
    "title": "Categorias dos Projetos",
    "show": "posts",
    "fields": [{
      "type": "checkbox ",
      "model": true
    }, {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "model": true
    }]

  }];
```

PERFECT WORLD:

```
  //GRUPOS CRIADOS SEGUIR ESTE JSON
  $scope.grupo = [{
    "fields": [{
      "type": "input",
      "title": "Nome do projeto",
      "key": "projeto-name",
      "obs": "Adicione aqui o nome do projeto."
      "model": "Projeto teste"

    }],
    "id": "1",
    "posted": "2015-08-05T06:42:11.598Z",
    "title": "Projetos",
    "show": "posts"
  }, {
    "fields": [{
      "type": "checkbox",
      "model": true
    }, {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "model": true
    }],
    "id": "2",
    "posted": "2015-08-06T22:37:16.046 Z",
    "title": "Categorias dos Projetos",
    "show": "posts"
  }];
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/S20jluwSyXncp74KyTn9?p=preview

Comment: updated the tags to attract more appropriate views; This is definitely JavaScript code, and there is nothing angular specific here.  Also added merge since that is what this function is meant to do.

Comment: `if (typeof result[i]!='undefined') { continue; }`

Comment: @CrayonViolent where i put this code?